# UITableView Swipe custom Button disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with my custom `UITableViewCell` when the swipe action is fired. I have a `UIStepper`, `UILabel`s and a `UIImage` in my cell, but when I swipe only the `UIStepper` element disappears. When finishing/canceling the swipe action, the `UIStepper` reappears after a short time.
Please see attached gif:

[image]

This is the code implementing the swipe action:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, handler) in
        print("Delete Action Tapped")
    }

    let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Edit") { (action, view, handler) in
        print("Add Action Tapped")
    }

    editAction.backgroundColor = .orange
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
    return configuration
}
```

Using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10 for iOS 12. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How is the stepper added to the cell?

Comment: It is added in a prototype cell in the Interface Builder and then connected to the custom `UITableViewCell` through an outlet. This is the same for the two `UILabel` and `UIImage`which seem to be working correctly with the swipe action.